# How to convert Mnesia query results to a JSON'able list?

Tags: json, erlang, mnesia

I am trying to use [JSX](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) to convert a list of tuples to a JSON object.

The list items are based on a record definition:

```
-record(player, {index, name, description}).
```

and looks like this:

```
[
    {player,1,"John Doe","Hey there"},
    {player,2,"Max Payne","I am here"}
]
```

The query function looks like this:

```
select_all() ->
    SelectAllFunction =
        fun() ->
            qlc:eval(qlc:q(
                [Player ||
                    Player <- mnesia:table(player)
                ]
            ))
        end,
    mnesia:transaction(SelectAllFunction).
```

What's the proper way to make it convertable to a JSON knowing that I have a schema of the record used and knowing the structure of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the record into a term that `jsx` can encode to JSON correctly. Assuming you want an array of objects in the JSON for the list of `player` records, you'll have to either convert each `player` to a map or list of tuples. You'll also have to convert the strings to binaries or else `jsx` will encode it to a list of integers. Here's some sample code:

```
-record(player, {index, name, description}).

player_to_json_encodable(#player{index = Index, name = Name, description = Description}) ->
    [{index, Index}, {name, list_to_binary(Name)}, {description, list_to_binary(Description)}].

go() ->
    Players = [
        {player, 1, "John Doe", "Hey there"},
        % the following is just some sugar for a tuple like above
        #player{index = 2, name = "Max Payne", description = "I am here"}
    ],
    JSON = jsx:encode(lists:map(fun player_to_json_encodable/1, Players)),
    io:format("~s~n", [JSON]).
```

Test:

```
1> r:go().
[{"index":1,"name":"John Doe","description":"Hey there"},{"index":2,"name":"Max Payne","description":"I am here"}]
```